# How do I split arguments with Ruby and Thor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation, thor

I've been learning Ruby and using Thor in a self-project and I would like to know, how do I split arguments using Thor. For example:

```
scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

I would like to know how to split `name:string`, `title:string` and `content:text` into an object array with "name" and "type".

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have a file `scaffold.rb` with following contents:

```
array = ARGV.map { |column_string| column_string.split(":").first }
puts array.inspect # or 'p array'
```

Then, if we run `ruby scaffold.rb name:string title:string content:text`, you will get

```
["name", "title", "content"]
```

If our code was `p ARGV`, then output will be `["name:string", "title:string", "content:text"]`. So, we will get whatever we pass after, `ruby scaffold.rb` as an array split by space in `ARGV` variable inside the code. We can manipulate this array as we wish, inside the code.

Disclaimer: I dont know Thor, but wanted to show how this is done in Ruby

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use whatever Rails uses so you're not reinventing the wheel. I dug around a little in the generator source and found that rails is using a [GeneratedAttribute](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb) class to convert the arguments to objects.

From the [generator named_base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb#L155) source you'll see they are splitting the arguments on ':' and passing those to `Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute`:

```
def parse_attributes! #:nodoc:
  self.attributes = (attributes || []).map do |key_value|
    name, type = key_value.split(':')
    Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute.new(name, type)
  end
end
```

You don't have to use the [GeneratedAttribute](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb) class, but it's there if you want it.

Answer (score -1):

```
"your:string:here".split(":") => ["your", "string", "here"]
```